# Meteor Accounts.loginWithPassword "400 Match Failed" Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm playing around with the Angular Meteor tutorial that uses Ionic to create a WhatsApp Clone. I changed the phone verification to a normal user setup using username/password.

Accounts are created using

```
    Accounts.createUser(email,password,callback)
```

When they logout and attempt to log back in, I have a form that an existing user can use to fill in their email and password. I cannot get the

```
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password,callback)
```

method to work for this scenario; it keeps saying that I have a 400 error, which is "Match failed". Below is my code for logging in to a user once the account has already been created:

Form:

```
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input ng-model="logger.existingEmail" on-return="logger.loginExistingUser()" type="text" placeholder="Your existing email">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input ng-model="logger.existingPassword" on-return="logger.loginExistingUser()" type="text" placeholder="Your existing password">
    </label>
```

JS:

```
    login() {
      if (_.isEmpty(this.existingEmail) ||_.isEmpty(this.existingPassword)) return;
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.existingEmail,this.existingPassword,function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
```

- I have created multiple accounts and tried the following:

  - logging in with email and password
  - logging in with user id and password (user id generated in mongodb)
  - passing in email and password directly to Meteor.loginWithPassword
  - passing in user id and directly to Meteor.loginWithPassword

The variables are valid just before the Meteor.loginWithPassword call.

I'm using:

```
    accounts-password 1.3.3
    meteor 1.4.2.3
```

Any tips? Sorry about the poor format of the post, I'm in a hurry and just wanted to get this question up. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try logging both your email and password to console before calling `Meteor.loginWithPassword`, there must be something wrong with their values

Comment: They are correct just before calling Meteor.loginWithPassword. also added in a username field to the register form just now, and am trying to login with username and password. still getting the error

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. The package

```
    mys:accounts-phone
```

was causing the error. Removed this package and login works as normal.