# MeteorJS: Match failed in Meteor.loginWithPassword()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I’m using accounts-password with email (instead of username). Very few users are getting an error logging in, so I’m finding it difficult to identify the issue. They are getting a `“match failed”` when I call `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password)`:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation in field username in field user.username at check (packages/check/match.js:35:15) at MethodInvocation.<anonymous> (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:266:3)...
```

It's not clear to me why it's trying to match username. I changed the call to use email explicitly, `Meteor.loginWithPassword({email:email},password)` , and get the same error, except the match fails on email:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation in field email in field user.email
 at check (packages/check/match.js:35:15)
 at MethodInvocation.<anonymous> (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:266:3)
```

I cannot reproduce this on demand (so hard to debug), but it does seem to happen to specific users, but not all the time. I am certain that the user is correctly entering email/password (and even if not, the error would not be a match failed). The email domains are restricted, so it's not an unusual email address or anything like that.

I am using accounts-password@1.5.0 with meteor 1.6.1.2. This does seem similar to [Meteor Accounts.loginWithPassword "400 Match Failed" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600480/meteor-accounts-loginwithpassword-400-match-failed-error), but I am not using the same package that was causing the issue there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Match error is resulted from `check()` (as illustrated by the execution stack in the error trace), so make sure you're passing a valid data. `Meteor.loginWithPassword` internally manages to find out where what you're passing is an email or a username.

```
  if (typeof selector === 'string')
    if (!selector.includes('@'))
      selector = {username: selector};
    else
      selector = {email: selector};
```

So, I presume you weren't passing a valid data in your first example and then in your second example it fails because you're passing it an object in the first place.

Comment: The second option is valid (passing an object with an email property) but agreed, should not be necessary. I'm not sure that I've fixed the issue, but checking that the two arguments passed to loginWithPassword are not empty strings seems to have resolved the issue (but cannot be 100% sure since it is so infrequent). I did witness a user logging in while getting the error and can confirm that they weren't passing in null strings, but perhaps the react component reading these in was not in-sync somehow and still passing nulls to login().